# What is the Active Record DSL for Querying Blobs with record id of the attachment?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activestorage

What is the correct and most performant Active Record DSL for the following query?

```
SELECT filename, content_type
FROM active_storage_blobs blobs
INNER JOIN active_storage_attachments attachments 
ON attachments.record_id = 3
WHERE blobs.id = attachments.blob_id
```

I am trying to select the filename and content type of a specific record in active_storage_blobs.

This is my image model with the file attachment:

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :file
end
```